# Keeping tools clean with clumping cat litter

Tags: cats, toilet-training

We use clumping cat litter for our cat toilets. The problem is that that stuff clumps so well that it will also stick to the scoop and the edges of the litter tray, and is really hard to remove. Is there anything I can do to prevent that? Not sure if this is a terrible idea, but I was wondering if I could spray them with a little cooking oil, but I'm afraid that would diminish the quality of the cat litter and/or irritate the cats?

Comment: Greaseproof paper?

Answer (score 3):

Get a nonstick cooking utensil for the purpose? Or one of the scoops that, like some toilet brushes, has a stand to hide it in when not in use.

I haven't had this problem, at least not any worse than with non-clumping litter. Stabbing the scoop into clean(ish) litter a few times will shake most accumulations free. I empty and refill the pan every month or so, and it it seems to need cleaning I do it then.

But realistically: It's a toilet. It's never going to be perfectly clean, any cleaning won't last long, and I don't really try to do more than keep it reasonably clear and acceptable to the cats. Having cats is like having infants, in terms of learning not to be overly squeamish about ejecta from either end...

Comment: I know it's a toilet and I have no problems with that. It's just that I find it quite hard to break of the clumps from the side of the litter tray (without scattering the litter everywhere!), and I would need a brush to free the scoop of accumulations. We recently switched back from non-clumping to clumping litter, so we might just need to try another brand, but I was hoping for some trick to make cleaning the litter box easier in general.

Comment: I dunno; I haven't had that problem, or at least not significantly. If you do change brands, I presume you know the trick of going thru several stages of mixed litters so the cats don't encounter a sudden strong difference and get confused...